# Formal Semantics - Set theory/Proofing (Not sure how to go around it)

Tags: semantics, computational-linguistics, formal-semantics

I've got to do a proof to explain for any s,

> [[former president with long hair]]<sub>s</sub> = {x: there is an s’ before s such that x is a president with long hair in s’}

when the structure is

> [former [president with long hair]]

based on the sentence "Sally is a former president with long hair". I've done a certain bit so far, but not sure if it's right.

Comment: As already said before: We can only give an answer to a question when you actually ask a question. "Explain semantics to me" is not one. Say *what* your precise problem is, where exactly you got stuck, why you got stuck and only then we might be able to help you.

Comment: i've got to do a proof to explain for any s, [[former president with long hair]]s = {x: there is an s’ before s such that x is a president with long hair in s’} when the structure is [former [president with long hair]] based on the sentence "Sally is a former president with long hair" ...i've done a certain bit so far, but not sure if it's right..

Comment: Then post this as your question. And include what exactly you don't understand, i.e. what you have tried so far and why you got stuck.

Comment: [with long hair]s = {x:x has long hair in s}        ASSUMP

[president[with long hair]]s = {x:x has long hair in s’} ∩ {x:x is a president in s’}             NB

[former[president with long hair]]s = {x:x has long hair in s’ and x is a president in s’} ∩ {x:x is a former president in s’}    NB

[[former president with long hair]]s = {x: there is an s’ before s such that x is a president with long hair in s’}        LEX

END OF PROOF

Comment: It just doesn't come out right on here though

Comment: @Julie I've tried to edit your comment inside your question. You should probably edit it to improve the wording and clarify your question, but at least now it's a question.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your comments above, I'm guessing that your task is to show how the principle of compositionality applies to the interpretation of your example "a former president with red hair".  If so, it was hard to figure that out, because you're using the terms "proof" and "explain" in an odd way.  I don't see how "proof" comes into it -- rather, you seem to want some appropriate observations.

The principle of compositionality, as I would express it, is that the interpretation of a complex expression is determined by the syntactic structure of the expression and is governed by the rule that the interpretation of the whole is determined by the interpretations of the parts, as those parts are given in the syntactic structure.  (A logician might use the term "morphological" where I have used "syntactic".)

In other words to figure out what an expression means, we find out its tree structure, then start at the bottom of the tree (the leaves, that is) and interpret the parts of the tree, working our way upwards, using previous results we got when we interpreted the lower, smaller parts.

For your example, then, the first step is to determine the syntactic structure.  Or more precisely, the syntactic structures, to allow for the possibility of ambiguities.

There does appear to be an ambiguity of syntactic structure involved here.  A noun phrase typically has a determiner followed by an N-bar (written N'), and an N' is either a noun or a modifier of some sort combined with an N'.  This is following McCawley's account in *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*.

So "a former president with red hair" combines the determiner "a" with the N' "former president with red hair", which in turn has two modifiers combined with the noun "president".  But there are two ways to build up that N' by combining the modifiers with what they modify.  The structure could be

```
[N' former [N' [N' president] with red hair]]
```

or

```
[N' [N' former [N' president]] with red hair]
```

So, correspondingly, there might be two different interpretations.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That's not quite what I mean, sorry